# How to build a protocol buffer message from a json using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, protocol-buffers

I've been trying to generate protocol buffer messages from a json string using gson. Does anyone know how if it is possible to do it?

I have already tried:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<PROTOBUFFMESSAGE.Builder>>() {}.getType();
List<PROTOBUFFMESSAGE.Builder> list = (List<PROTOBUFFMESSAGE.Builder>) gson.fromJson(aJsonString, type);
```

<strike>and</strike>

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<PROTOBUFFMESSAGE>>() {}.getType();
List<PROTOBUFFMESSAGE> list = (List<PROTOBUFFMESSAGE>) gson.fromJson(aJsonString, type);
```

The message inside the json uses the same names as in the protocol buffer i.e:

```
message PROTOBUFFMESSAGE {
   optional string this_is_a_message = 1;
   repeated string this_is_a_list = 2;
}
```

will lead to a json:

```
[
    {
        "this_is_a_message": "abc",
        "this_is_a_list": [
            "123",
            "qwe"
        ]
    },
    {
        "this_is_a_message": "aaaa",
        "this_is_a_list": [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ]
    }
]
```

Although a list with the correct number of PROTOBUFFMESSAGE gets generated, they contain all their fields to null, so I'm not sure if this is a problem with the mapping, the reflection system not detecting protobuffs fields or something else. If anyone know how to do this it would be great. Btw I'm talking about java here.

## EDIT:

changing the names in the json to:

```
        {
            "thisIsAMessage_": "abc",
            "thisIsAList_": [
                "123",
                "qwe"
            ]
        }
```

Makes the de serialization happen. And it does work except for the list that throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList field Helper$...etc big path here...$PROTOBUFFMESSAGE$Builder.thisIsAList_ to java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: if open code for generated message with protobuf then `optional string this_is_a_message = 1;` would be become `private String this_is_a_message_;` note last underscore and setters/getters.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov That does work but with the Syntax `thisIsAMessage_`. The problem now is that the list `thisIsAList_` is generated with an `UnmodifiableLazyStringList` that throws an exception when deserializing :\

Comment: what exception? deserialization means at receiver side?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList field Helper$...etc...PROTOBUFFMESSAGE$Builder.thisIsAList_ to java.util.ArrayList`

I'm looking at the stacktrace to see if I can identify the problem, still tks for the help so far

Comment: The exception comes from GSON or Protobuf?

Comment: it is encapsulated in gson but comes from the proto

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll have to use `GsonBuilder` to build a `Gson` object, and write and register a type adapter to it for `com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initiating `Gson` object through a constructor use this snippet:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(LazyStringList.class, new TypeAdapter<LazyStringList>() {

  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, LazyStringList strings) throws IOException {

  }

  @Override
  public LazyStringList read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    LazyStringList lazyStringList = new LazyStringArrayList();

    in.beginArray();

    while (in.hasNext()) {
      lazyStringList.add(in.nextString());
    }

    in.endArray();

    return lazyStringList;
  }
});
```